# Dismissible container and ListView item not the same size

Tags: flutter, dart

> I just started learning flutter and am trying to build a todo app, the problem I encountered was the Dismissible container and the todo list view item have different heights and after trying everything I still couldn't fix it, the next problem was that the todo item would be dismissed from left to right whereas the container would go up. Any help would be much appreciated. My code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List todos = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _titleController = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _detailController = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    todos.add('');
    _titleController.add(TextEditingController());
    _detailController.add(TextEditingController());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 24.0,
          ),
          color: const Color(0xfff6f6f6f6),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32.0, top: 32.0),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Reminders",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: todos.length,
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Dismissible(
                            background: buildActionSwipeLeft(),
                            onDismissed: (direction) {
                              setState(() {
                                todos.removeAt(index);
                                _titleController.removeAt(index);
                                _detailController.removeAt(index);
                                DismissDirection.startToEnd;
                              });
                            },
                            direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                            key: Key(todos[index]),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 15.0
                              ),
                              child: Card(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                elevation: 4,
                                child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 15.0,
                                        horizontal: 24.0
                                    ),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        TextField(
                                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                          controller: _titleController[index],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                          ),
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: "Enter a title",
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const Divider(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller: _detailController[index],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20.0,
                                              color: Colors.grey[900],
                                            ),
                                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                            maxLines: null,
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                hintText: "Enter the description",
                                                label: Text("description"),
                                                border: InputBorder.none
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      todos.add('');
                      _titleController.add(TextEditingController());
                      _detailController.add(TextEditingController());
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 35.0),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildActionSwipeLeft() => Container(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
  child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
);
```

Comment: To dismiss left to right use a key: ` key: UniqueKey()`I however cant understand what you want to achieve with the list items. Please provide an illustration or an image of the design or elaborate further

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately I am not able to add an image cause my reputation is low

Comment: Post the image on twitter and tag me @avis_code  . That's the only way I can help

Comment: Sorry but I don't have Twitter, Basically, the problem I faced was that on sliding the list item the height of the red container that appears is different from the height of the list item.

Comment: From your code there is no red container

Comment: Its the buildActionSwipeLeft() widget, the color of the widget is red and has a delete icon.

Comment: You want the height of the red container to be smaller or bigger?

Comment: I want it to be smaller

Comment: I think I know why that happened, its because of the padding applied to the list tile right below the key. So to fix that I applied padding to the buildActionSwipeLeft().

Comment: Cool you can work with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List todos = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _titleController = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _detailController = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    todos.add('');
    _titleController.add(TextEditingController());
    _detailController.add(TextEditingController());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 24.0,
          ),
          color: const Color(0xfff6f6f6f6),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32.0, top: 32.0),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Reminders",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: todos.length,
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Stack(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0,left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                              child: buildActionSwipeLeft(),
                            ),
                            Dismissible(
                              onDismissed: (direction) {
                                setState(() {
                                  todos.removeAt(index);
                                  _titleController.removeAt(index);
                                  _detailController.removeAt(index);
                                  DismissDirection.startToEnd;
                                });
                              },
                              direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                child: Card(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 4,
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        TextField(
                                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                          controller: _titleController[index],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: "Enter a title",
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const Divider(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller:
                                                _detailController[index],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20.0,
                                              color: Colors.grey[900],
                                            ),
                                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                            maxLines: null,
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                hintText:
                                                    "Enter the description",
                                                label: Text("description"),
                                                border: InputBorder.none),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      todos.add('');
                      _titleController.add(TextEditingController());
                      _detailController.add(TextEditingController());
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    child:
                        const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 35.0),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildActionSwipeLeft() => Container(
  height: 180,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
      child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
    );
```

Achieving this has a disadvantage of loosing a few animation. Will research more:

Comment: Nice, but How did you make the buildActionSwipeLeft widget just disappear after the list view item was dismissed? because before it just used to go up after dismissal.

Comment: What do you mean? I added it as a stack child instead of background.

Comment: I fixed the problem by wrapping the dismissible widget under ClipRRect and wrapping ClipRRect under Card widget, so both the list item and the dismissible were under the card widget and had the same height.

Comment: Oh cool!!!!!!!!